# How to tolerate a wrong argument type in json with Jackson?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I am integrating with a third party API that responses with an object like this:

```
{
  "name": {
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe"
  }
}
```

The corresponding Java class looks like this:

```
class Name {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}
```

**Problem:** When the name is supposed to be `null` the API returns an empty string instead of `null` or an empty object:

```
{
  "name": ""
}
```

**Questing:** How to tolerate this behavior on the client side keeping in mind that I call the API using Spring's `RestTemplate` and `Jackson`?

In other words, how can I tell Jackson to treat an empty string passed into the `name` attribute as null, or as an object of the class `Name` with null properties?

Note: It is not possible to make the API work correctly. I have to handle it on my side.

Comment: Could you please provide some more info. What do you want to do when you get `"name":""`? There are several ways to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

You either use `try / catch` and handle the error. Or you write your own Deserializer if you have to handle different scenarios.

Try Catch

```java
Name name;
try {
    // Your restTemplate code, will throw Exception when cannot serialize
} catch (Execption e) {
    name = null;
}
```

Deserializer docs:
https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonDeserializer.html

Example on how you can deserialize (not tested)

```java
// On your class specify Deserialzer
@JsonDeserialize(using = YourNameClassDeserializer.class)
public class YourNameClass {
    // your class here
}

// Your Deserializer class
public class YourNameClassDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Item> { 

    @Override
    public Item deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
        // Use JsonNode to figure out what you are getting and create the object by yourself
        return new YourNameClass(firstName, lastName);
    }
}
```

You can one of these solution, both will work for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Jackson has a deserialization feature for this called [`ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRINGS_AS_NULL_OBJECTS`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT). With Spring boot, you can enable this by enabling the following property within `application.properties`:

```
spring.jackson.deserialization.accept-empty-string-as-null-object=true
```

After that, Jackson will deserialize empty strings as `null`.

Be aware, since this is a global deserialization feature, this will also happen when the first name would be an empty string.

Comment: You probably misunderstood the question. _Name is a class_. And the issue is that the API sometimes returns _a composite object_ and sometimes, when it is supposed to return null, _a string_.

Comment: @SashaShpota You're right, my mind mixed the firstName/lastName/name fields. Anyhow, I edited my answer to show an alternative way by using the `ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRINGS_AS_NULL_OBJECTS` deserialization feature.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This should work. I would say you need to change your java model a bit.

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = NameDeserializer.class)
public class NameWrapper {
    private Name name;

    public NameWrapper() {
    }

    public NameWrapper(Name name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Name getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(Name name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Name class will be like

```
public class Name {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Name() {
    }

    public Name(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

And lastly the deserializer

```
public class NameDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer {
    @Override
    public NameWrapper deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException
```

{

```
        ObjectCodec oc = jsonParser.getCodec();
        JsonNode node = oc.readTree(jsonParser);
        if(node.get("name").get("firstName") == null && node.get("name").textValue().isEmpty())
                return null;
        else {
             String firstName = node.get("name").get("firstName").textValue();
             String lastName = node.get("name").get("lastName").textValue();

            return  new NameWrapper(new Name(firstName, lastName));
        }
    }
}
```

This would work with both these json's

```
{
  "name": {
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe"
  }
}
```

and

```
{
  "name": ""
}
```